# simple fade transition - not reverse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-transitions, reversing

I have a simple div which the transition is toggle using the Jquery toggle function.

The problem I am having is the effect does not go in reverse?

```
$('.mydiv').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.mydiv').not(this).addClass('inactive');
})

$('.mydiv').on('mouseout', function() {
    $('.mydiv').removeClass('inactive');
})
```

```css
.mydiv {
    width: 520px;
    height: 260px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    transition:all 10s ease; 
    opacity: 1;
}

.mydiv.inactive {
    transition:all 10s ease; 
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Comment: As per your code, It is working fine for me. It is taking 10s time to for `opacity:0.2` and 0.2s time for revert back.

Answer (score 1):

there is another way to do it by using css only.

```
 .mydiv {
        width: 520px;
        height: 260px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom:40px;
         transition:all 10s ease; 
         opacity: 1;
         transition:all 10s ease;
    }
   .mydiv:hover {
      opacity: 0.2;
   }
```

working sample https://jsfiddle.net/69wn8046/1/

Answer (score 0):

At `mouseover` you want `.mydiv selector to addClass .inactive` on second line you are preventing it from adding that, and 2nd is `transition-duration` you have declared that has `10s` `transition:all 10s ease;` reduce that to see reverse effect.

```js
  $('.mydiv').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('inactive');
});

 $('.mydiv').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('inactive');
});
```

```css
.mydiv {
        width: 520px;
        height: 260px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom:40px;
         transition:all 1s ease; 
         opacity: 1;
         background:#111;
    }


    .mydiv.inactive {
         transition:all 1s ease; 
         opacity: 0.2;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">

</div>
```